# How does NumPy assemble an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, ipython

I've recently come noticed a behaviour in numpy that I find interesting. I'm assembling an uniform array with shape (17544,520,1200). When I build it this way:

```
import numpy as np
import time

t0 = time.time()

# method 1
array = np.ones((17544,520,1200))

t1=time.time()
print(t1-t0)
#46.65...
```

The array is constructed without a problem. But when I try:

```
# method 2
array = np.ones((520,1200,17544))
```

My ipython shell crashes (`zsh: killed     ipython`)

Why is this?

Additional note: this is for iterating over each element of a 520x1200 array, and, if that element is non-zero, replacing the axis of size 17544 with a 1D array of that size. Is there a better way to do this other than element-wise iteration and insertion?

Comment: That sounds like you just hit memory limits, and the array shapes had nothing to do with it besides being very large.

Comment: (Seriously, those arrays are like 87 gigabytes each.)

Comment: Crap, I had no idea they were that large. I knew it would be gigabytes but nothing like that. I need to completely iterate and insert new values over these for 77 different conditions. I'd planned to do it in a for loop, creating a new array, saving as a netcdf, and repeating for the next. Do you think it will be possible that way?

Comment: You can tell the size of an array by multiplying the shape and the item size. Float64s are 8 bytes, so 8*17544*520*1200

Comment: That also explains why it took 46 seconds to allocate

Comment: Try method2 in a fresh ipython session